# @DELETE not working in AngularJS + JAVA+CORS

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, cors

I've been playing around AngularJS for a few weeks now... and I ran into a corner...
The scenario:

A Java REST(Resteasy) on localhost:8080 (where you see company.com is localhost)

A AnguljarJS APP served by grunt on 9001

The JAVA end is using the CORS filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and the method

```
@DELETE
@Path("/{id}")
public void delete(@PathParam("id")Long id);
```

It doesn't make any difference if I add the "@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })"

THE AngularJS Side:
Service:

```
service.factory('SensorTypeService', function($resource){
return $resource('http://company.com:8080/hackstation-web/service/sensortype/:Id',
    {Id: '@Id'},
    {
        'update': {method: 'POST'},
        'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
        'reviews': {'method': 'GET', 'params': {'reviews_only': 'true'}, isArray: true}

    });
```

});

the call:

```
$scope.delete = function(id){
    SensorTypeService.remove({},{'Id': id}, function(){
        $scope.refresh();
    });
};
```

So far, what I discovered:
If I run:
curl http://company.com:8080/hackstation-web/service/sensortype/9 -X DELETE

On terminal, works fine!! the method is called on the JAVA SIDE and it gets deleted.

On my application, I can see all the GET POST methods on the firebug's console, but the DELETE doesn't show, up. But I can debug the method and I can see that goes from the angularjs-resource.js to the angular.js I can see the method is set to DELETE, the Accept is the type json in plain text.... it looks like its allright... but somehow it just dosent go!

I have read a lot of similar questions here, tried a bunch of them, and got nothing.

As far as I could see, the url is created like it should be, the accept is there and the method is DELETE. but somehow it just dosent appear on the console.

BTW, all the other method query, update... all works fine!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By default CORSFilter only supports **GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS**. You should add **DELETE** to supportedMethods list:

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Details are [here](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-configuration.html)